# How to make MySQL data display in 2 columns?

Tags: php, mysql

I am wanting to make the data to show in 2 columns instead of one here is the code I currently use to show the data in 1 column:

```
    <?php 
include("config.php");
include("opendb.php");
$get_cats = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `categories` ORDER BY `displayorder`") or die(mysql_error());
$get_info = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `systeminfo`") or die(mysql_error());
$info = mysql_fetch_array($get_info);
while($cats = mysql_fetch_array($get_cats)) {
$get_rares = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `rares` WHERE `catid`='".$cats['id']."'") or die(mysql_error());
echo("<h2>".$cats['name']."</h2><br>
<table width=\"100%\" border=\"0\">
<tr>
<td width=\"20%\" style=\"text-align:center\"><b>Image</b></td>
<td width=\"40%\" style=\"text-align:left\"><b>Item Name</b></td>
<td width=\"10%\" style=\"text-align:center\"><b>Value</b></td>
<td width=\"30%\" style=\"text-align:center\"><b>Last Updated</b></td>
</tr>
");
$color1 = $info[stripe1]; 
$color2 = $info[stripe2];
$row_count = 0;
while($rare = mysql_fetch_array($get_rares)) {
$row_color = ($row_count % 2) ? $color1 : $color2;
?>
<tr>
<td width="5%" style="text-align:center;background-color:#<?php echo $row_color; ?>"><img alt="" src="<?php echo("".$info[imagepath]."".$rare['image'].""); ?>"></td>
<td width="20%" style="text-align:left;background-color:#<?php echo $row_color; ?>"><?php echo $rare['name']; ?></td>
<td width="20%" style="text-align:center;background-color:#<?php echo $row_color; ?>"><?php echo $rare['value']; ?> Credits</td>
<td width="10%" style="text-align:center;background-color:#<?php echo $row_color; ?>"><?php echo $rare['lastedited']; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php 
$row_count++;
}
echo("</table><br>

");
}
?>
```

Currently is shows as:

```
1
_________

2
_________

3
_________

4
_________

5
_________

6
_________
```

I would like it to show like this:

```
1         | 2
_________ | _________
3         | 4
_________ | _________
5         | 6
_________ | _________
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what it's worth, I encorporated MarcB's code into your original code.  You were already doing the mod with your row count.  I think you want something like this:

```
<?php 
include("config.php");
include("opendb.php");

$get_cats = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `categories` ORDER BY `displayorder`") or die(mysql_error());
$get_info = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `systeminfo`") or die(mysql_error());
$info = mysql_fetch_array($get_info);
while($cats = mysql_fetch_array($get_cats)) {
        $get_rares = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `rares` WHERE `catid`='".$cats['id']."'") or die(mysql_error());
        echo("<h2>".$cats['name']."</h2><br>
                <table width=\"100%\" border=\"0\">
                <tr>
                        <td width=\"20%\" style=\"text-align:center\"><b>Image</b></td>
                        <td width=\"40%\" style=\"text-align:left\"><b>Item Name</b></td>
                        <td width=\"10%\" style=\"text-align:center\"><b>Value</b></td>
                        <td width=\"30%\" style=\"text-align:center\"><b>Last Updated</b></td>
                        <td width=\"20%\" style=\"text-align:center\"><b>Image2</b></td>
                        <td width=\"40%\" style=\"text-align:left\"><b>Item Name2</b></td>
                        <td width=\"10%\" style=\"text-align:center\"><b>Value2</b></td>
                        <td width=\"30%\" style=\"text-align:center\"><b>Last Updated2</b></td>
                </tr>
                ");

        $color1 = $info[stripe1]; 
        $color2 = $info[stripe2];

        $row_count = 0;

        while($rare = mysql_fetch_array($get_rares)) {
                $row_color = ($row_count % 2) ? $color1 : $color2;
                if ($row_count % 2 == 0) {
                        echo "<tr>"; // if on an 'even' record, start a new row
                }

                echo "<td width='5%' style='text-align:center;background-color:#$row_color;'><img alt='' src='{$info[imagepath]}{$rare['image']}'></td>
                                <td width='20%' style='text-align:left;background-color:#$row_color;'>{$rare['name']}</td>
                                <td width='20%' style='text-align:center;background-color:#$row_color;'>{$rare['value']} Credits</td>
                                <td width='10%' style='text-align:center;background-color:#$row_color;'>{$rare['lastedited']}</td>";

                if ($row_count % 2 == 0) {
                        echo "</tr>"; // close the row if we're on an even record
                }

                $row_count++;
        }

        echo "</table><br/>";
}
```

?>

Comment: Hi, I am getting the following error: 
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_IF, expecting ',' or ';' in /home/.../public_html/values/show_rares.php on line 40

Comment: Fixed ";" was missing after the last </td>", Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

This really doesn't have anything to do with MySQL at all. MySQL's just the source of the data. You'd want something like this:

```
$record = 0;
while($rare = mysql_fetch_array($get_rares)) {
    if ($record % 2 == 0) {
       echo "<tr>"; // if on an 'even' record, start a new row
    }
    echo "<td>{$rare['something']}</td>";
    $record++;
    if ($record % 2 == 0) {
       echo "</tr>"; // close the row if we're on an even record
    }
}
```